# How do I upgrade to Windows 7 from a non-booting Vista installation?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, boot, upgrade

My laptop came presupplied with a Vista Professional installation and no Vista installation DVD. It has now stopped booting, stuck in a cycle of failing startup repairs.

I have a Windows 7 Ultimate DVD, but when I boot from it and select the option to upgrade an existing Windows installation, it states that the upgrade should be performed from within the existing Windows installation as a live upgrade.

Without being able to load the original Vista installation, how can I perform an upgrade to Windows 7 without losing my user accounts and installed programs?

Although I back up most of my data I really need to get the upgrade working in order to sanity check that I'm not losing anything important.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried recovering your Vista installation using the Vista recovery disk? Download it [here](http://neosmart.net/blog/2008/windows-vista-recovery-disc-download/), burn it and boot from it.

Comment: @BloodPhilia: thanks for the link. I'm currently writing from my iPhone as I don't have another machine with a DVD writer until work tomorrow. Anymore suggestions until I can try this?

Comment: @user17873 - No, if you want to perform an upgrade, getting Vista to work again will be your top-priority.

Comment: I've been reading that a clean installation actually copies the previous installation to a windows.old folder. Can aynone confirm 100% that I will have access to all previous user / desktop files after a clean installation?

Comment: @user17873 - Yes all such information will be copied to your new installation.

Comment: Can you please describe what is copied where etc so that I have confidence in performing the clean installation?

Comment: @user17873 - The entire user profile of every used should be retained, this includes documents, desktop, etc. everything in `C:\Users` probably. I would recommend on backup up before though... there's always a chance something goes wrong.

Comment: Link no longer allows download of the Vista disc.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to repair the Vista installation to do an Upgrade to preserve your accounts and settings. Here is a link to the advanced methods of boot repair, it will require the recovery disc mentioned by BloodPhilia, or borrow a Vista Install disc from someone to repair. Or try the W7 disc you have to repair the boot issue.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392/en-us

.